# How to modify an array of array, depending if an element in it matches an element from another array of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 set of array of arrays in Google Spreadsheet as follows:-

```
var arrayInput = [[ASIAPLY, "9/10/2020"], [PCCS, "9/10/2020"], [SCGM, "9/10/2020"]]

var arrayOuput = [[PCCS, "8/10/2020"]]
```

I want to insert the 2nd index of an element/array in the arrayInput if the 1st index is present in the outputArray. If it is not, I would like to add the whole element/array into outputArray. My desired outcome would look like this

```
var arrayOuput = [[PCCS, "9/10/2020", "8/10/2020"], [ASIAPLY, "9/10/2020"], [SCGM, "9/10/2020"]]
```

I have tried this

```
function testData() {
  
  // get the range of input data
  var arrayInput = wlSheet.getRange(2, 2, 3, 2).getValues(); 
  
  // get the range of output counter
  var arrayOuput = wlSheet.getRange(2, 7, 1, 2).getValues();
  
  arrayOuput.find((outputRow, i, arr) => {
  
    arrayInput.map((r, index, array) => {
    
    if (r[0] !== outputRow[0]) {
      return wlSheet.getRange(arr.length + 2 + index, 7, 1, 2).setValues([[counter, hyperlinkText]]);
    } else {
      return wlSheet.getRange(i + 2, 8).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS).setValue(hyperlinkText);
    }
    });
  });

}
```

However the code above has resulted into [[PCCS, "9/10/2020", "8/10/2020"], [PCCS, "9/10/2020"], [ASIAPLY, "9/10/2020"], [SCGM, "9/10/2020"]]; instead of desired result.

Is there a way of achieving what I intended to do in Google Apps Script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **insert** an item, you can't use `Array.prototype.map` as it will return a new array.

Now i'm not familiar with google apps scripts, or interacting with spreadsheets, but the basic JS would look like this:

What you are trying can be easily done with a [for...of-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

The basic steps are:

- we have two arrays in the shape of a `key` followed by a number of values

  - if your familiar with TypeScript types: [key: Key, ...values: string[]]
- we want to take *from* `input` *to* `output`

  - for each element in `input`

    - if output **has** an element with the corresponding key: append own values to it
    - else add self to output

```js
const inArr = [['ASIAPLY', '9/10/2020'], ['PCCS', '9/10/2020'], ['SCGM', '9/10/2020']]
const outArr = [['PCCS', '8/10/2020']]
// iterate over the array elements and use destructuring to
// extract the key form the other values
for (const [key, ...values] of arrayInput) {
  // look for an element in `output` that has that key
  const target = outArr.find(([ky, value]) => ky === key)
  // if we found one, push the values to it
  if (target) target.push(...values)
  // else push your key-values onto the output array
  else outArr.push([key, ...values])
}
```

The result using the example arrays is:

```js
[
  [ 'PCCS', '8/10/2020', '9/10/2020' ],
  [ 'ASIAPLY', '9/10/2020' ],
  [ 'SCGM', '9/10/2020' ]
]
```

Since we used [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...values`) in the [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), this is little iterator is able to handel 0 or more values by default and will always output the approptiate result.

This should solve this problem in an elegant manner and it is easyly modifiable if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the .push to .splice since i want the element of inArr to be on the 2nd index of outArr, otherwise it is a nicer code than mine.

Comment: @Abenexus sure, adjust it as needed. I tried to make it as generic as possible

Answer (score 0):

Create a new output array using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)  and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
const array1 = [
    ['ASIAPLY', '9/10/2020'],
    ['PCCS', '9/10/2020'],
    ['SCGM', '9/10/2020'],
  ],
  array2 = [['PCCS', '8/10/2020']],
  array2Map = new Map(array2),
  arrayOutput = array1.map(([k, v]) => [k, v, array2Map.get(k)]);
console.log(arrayOutput);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

To use `setValues`,  the arrays must be of uniform size.

Comment: your code inserts the arrayOutput into arrayInput, instead of other way around. I'll tinker with code a bit, since this is my first time seeing a Map object/constructor.

Thanks

Comment: @Abenexus What's the difference? You finally get a combined array. Isn't that what you want?